# custom Constraint in Play 2.0-scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to write a custom Constraint to use it in my Form for validation. Mappings in Form have a verifying function: `verifying (constraints: Constraint[T]*): Mapping[T]`.

I can obviously use the built in constraints, e.g. `"name" -> text.verifying(nonEmpty)`.

Now I need my own constraint though. The Constraint case class looks like: `case class Constraint [-T] (name: Option[String], args: Seq[Any], f: (T) ⇒ ValidationResult) extends Product with Serializable`

But when I looked at ValidationResult, I just see an empty trait, see here - http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.2/scala/index.html#play.api.data.validation.ValidationResult. So how can I define my own Constraint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your problem that you don't know how to create a function of type `T => ValidationResult`? If you click on the "known subclasses", it has two: `Invalid` (a class) and `Valid` (a singleton).

So for example:

```
import play.api.data.validation._

val f = (_: Int) match {
  case 0 | 1 | 2 => Valid
  case _ => Invalid("Number over 2")
}

val c = Constraint("my constraint")(f)
```

Comment: bingo..that was exactly my issue